# Problems happend when i create a text file

Tags: c, linux, file-io

This is my code :

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define FILE "./test.txt"
char buf[20]="Hello, World!";
int main()
{
    int fd;
    if((fd=open(FILE,O_EXCL|O_CREAT))==-1)
    {
        printf("File Already EXIST!\n");
        if((fd=open(FILE,O_RDWR))==-1)
        {
            perror("open error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if((fd=open(FILE,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0666))==-1)
        {
            perror("create error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if(write(fd,buf,sizeof(buf))==-1)
    {
        perror("write error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else printf("Write Done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, strange things happen. The text file's mode is different each time I run it (to test the create function, I rm the text file after running the program). So, why does this happen?

Comment: It would be worth adding some debug output to find out which way the file was created.

Comment: `#define FILE "./test.txt"` is a bad idea. `FILE` is a struct defined in `<stdio.h>` and it is used for standard (non-POSIX) file handling. **Just don't do this.** Fix your code and come back when you eliminated all the undefined behaviors. (Where, seriously, you people are getting these ideas??)

Comment: While I 100% agree that using `#define FILE` is horrid, it does not actually cause any problem (undefined behaviour) in this code (by fluke, for the most part, but still, no problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`).

```
 #define FILE "./test.txt"
```

is inappropriate (conflicts with `FILE` from `<stdio.h>`) and should be

```
 #define FILE_NAME "./test.txt"
```

then

```
 if((fd=open(FILE,O_EXCL|O_CREAT))==-1)
```

is wrong. [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) needs a third *mode* argument (when passing `O_CREAT` at least).

<sup>The kernel needs a mode when creating any file, e.g. thru `open` with `O_CREAT`. When opening an existing file, the mode is useless, so is documented as unneeded, but something useless is passed to the kernel.</sup>

Some garbage is passed instead of the missing third argument (and that explains the non-reproducible [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). Try instead

```
 fd = open(FILE_NAME, O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0640);
 if (fd < 0)
```

BTW, you could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program to understand the syscalls it is doing.

Comment: According to http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/unixio.html, (and your link), both two-parameter and three=parameter versions of the function are valid... so no need for third argument.

Comment: The *mode* third argument *is needed when a file is created*

Comment: @Floris: If you specify O_CREAT, you must also specify the third argument.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JonathanLeffler and Basile. Clearly I need to learn to read the _whole_ documentation...